# How to call masterpage function in a usercontrol page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to call masterpage public function on usercontrol cs page.

whether this user control is called on the master page.

My user control is on the master page and i want to calling this master page function in this usercontrol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Call function in MasterPage through UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444218/asp-net-call-function-in-masterpage-through-usercontrol)

Comment: yes its same but its not works...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an event in the User control and subscribe that event in the Master page. Invoke the master page function in the event handler.

UserControl

```
public event void DoSomething(object o, EventArgs e);
```

Master Page

```
UserControl.DoSomething += (o, e)=>
{
//Invoke Master Page function.
};
```

Comment: i want to call master page function in usercontrol page not usercontrol function into masterpage...